# Regular expression for nested tags

Tags: regex, nested

I am developing an extension to highlight some custom scripting code and I need a regular expression that can capture the text between <> (including the outer tags and nested)

example link: https://regex101.com/r/7AkKRU/1

or

small demo (content needed to be capture will be commented):

```
IF !(<isempty <ctag.add_sub>>) //<isempty <ctag.add_sub>>
    if (<ctag0.add_sub_page>) //<ctag0.add_sub_page>
        local.index=<eval 14*<ctag.add_sub_page>> //<eval 14*<ctag.add_sub_page>>
    endif
    local.sub=<LDB.Row.<dctag.add_sub>.subsection> //<LDB.Row.<dctag.add_sub>.subsection>
    LDB.query "SELECT rowid,description FROM <ctag.add_mode> WHERE subsection = '<local.sub>'" //<ctag.add_mode> <local.sub>
    dtext 516 45 0480 Page (<eval <ctag0.add_sub_page>+1>/<eval (<ldb.row.numrows>/14)+1>) //<eval <ctag0.add_sub_page>+1> <eval (<ldb.row.numrows>/14)+1>
    for 0 13
        local.desc=<ldb.row.<dlocal.num>.description> //<ldb.row.<dlocal.num>.description>
        if (<dlocal.num>< <ldb.row.numrows>) //<dlocal.num> <ldb.row.numrows>
            button 760 <dlocal.dy> 4005 4007 1 0 <eval 100000+<dlocal.rowid>> //<dlocal.dy> <eval 100000+<dlocal.rowid>>
        endif
    endfor
    IF (<ldb.row.numrows> > <eval <local.index>+14>) //<ldb.row.numrows> <eval <local.index>+14>
    endif       
endif
```

At the moment I have the following regex (don't remember where I copied from, sorry):

```
(?=\<)(?:(?=.*?\<(?!.*?\1)(.*\>(?!.*\2).*))(?=.*?\>(?!.*?\2)(.*)).)+?.*?(?=\1)[^\<]*(?=\2$)
```

It works fine, **but when the > is the last element of the line it grabs extra content.**

UPDATE:
this was marked as duplicated but it is not the same (even though they are very similar), this is not for HTML/XHTML/XML, my problem is that the tag is not named (content) like in these languages, I have to match only the tags < >.

Comment: Don't write regex to match code. This applies to HTML exactly the same way as it applies to your custom script code. What kind of language is this, by the way? And what language are you using to process this?

Comment: It is for  sphere server scripts (emulator for Ultima Online). Btw this is the regex I'm using now and it is working great `\<(.+?)[\w\S\>]*\>`

Comment: You can make this shorter: `<.+?[\S>]*>`. However, I'd say it's not working great - it fails things like `<eval <local.index> + 14>`, which I suppose are legal?

Comment: You are right,I didn't notice that since the file I'm using as test case it always is written like `<eval <local.index>+14>`

Comment: Yes... this is exactly the problem with using regex for these kinds of tasks - they have no concept of nesting. Any language that supports nested structures (like nested sets of `<` and `>`, or nested sets of `if` and `endif` etc.) is more complex than regex can handle. You will not be able to write a regex that can parse this code properly, it's impossible on a fundamental level. Some regex dialects (most prominently pcre) have extensions that *might* be able to help you get something that is good enough, but it depends on which regex dialect you can use here.

Comment: In more general terms, you would need to use (or write) a parser that can understand this scripting language, so you can pick the items you want from the syntax tree that the parser produces. A very cheap version would be like *"loop over all characters in the script. when you see a `<`, increment a counter and remember the current string position. when you see another `<`, increment the counter and move on. When you see `>`, decrement the counter. When the counter reaches 0, cut the string from the remembered position to the current position and output that substring. repeat."*